# How to disable global proxy settings for all applications exept IE in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, proxy, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am experiencing some troubles with Windows and Internet Explorer proxy settings.

To access some sites I **MUST** use http/https proxy and the same time I **MUST** use IE 11.

On Windows 10 Internet Explorer proxy settings is the same as system proxy setting. When I swith on proxy most of Windows services and applications is hangs because they server hosts are not available throuth my proxy.

Some applications (Dropbox, TeamViewer) has proxy settins with choice:

- none
- automatocally
- custom ....

But other apps (Microsoft Store, iCloud) has no one.

So my question is how to disable global proxy settings for all applications exept IE in Windows 10?

Comment: You could try a [proxifier](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/route-all-internet-software-and-game-connection-through-open-proxy-servers/) for `iexplore.exe`.

Comment: Yes, it's Work!   
harrymc, please re-post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to proxify only a specific executable, which for IE11 is `iexplore.exe`.

Here are some such free products:

- [FreeCap](http://www.freecap.ru/eng/?p=download)
- [WideCap](http://widecap.ru/en/download/)
- [Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com/download/)
- [ProxyCap](http://www.proxycap.com/download.html)

For an article with reviews of these products see
[4 Apps to Route All Internet Connection Through Open Proxy Servers](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/route-all-internet-software-and-game-connection-through-open-proxy-servers/).